Одна директория пушится как ссылка
Я написал бэк и фронт, они находятся в одной папке и разделены на папки back и front.
При пуше в GitHub, фронт пушится как обычно, а бэк пушиться в виде ссылки.

Я предполагаю, что дело в nestJS, который сам по себе создает локальный репозиторий в проекте, т.е. в папке back.

Может это символическая ссылка?

Проблема в том, что по самой ссылке ничего нет, 404.
Вот сама ссылка https://github.com/ziki1337/jsonSort/blob/master/back

Погуглите, что такое символическая ссылка. Надо перед тем как пушить, заменить ее на настоящую папку.

Это не символическая ссылка, самая обычная папка

Как вы это определили?

Через powershell

Как именно через powershell?

$item = Get-Item "...\jsonSort\back"
if ($item.Attributes -band [System.IO.FileAttributes]::ReparsePoint) {
Write-Output "Папка является символической ссылкой или точкой соединения."
} else {
Write-Output "Папка не является символической ссылкой."
}
Только путь в запросе был указан правильно

Это сабмодуль: https://i.sstatic.net/DR3ofw4E.png чтобы он был доступен, он тоже должен быть опубликован на гихабе, как отдельный репозиторий (по идее)

@insolor Спасибо за подсказку, я решил проблему обычной копией файлов из сабмодуля в новую папку.

Это не решение. У вас таким образом непонятно что будет, пока основной проект будет развиваться.
